# Search for child items matching certain name values

Tags: rest, postman, sitecore9

[This page](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-odata-item-service.html) describes how to retrieve an item, (immediate) child items and searching in `Sitecore9` using the `RESTful API` (via `PostMan`).

What it doesn't appear to say is how to combine those queries.

I would like to search the `children` of an `item` which is specified by `path`. So, currently, I have this returning an item:

```
GET https://{{sitecorehost}}/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('{{sitecorehome}}/banners-tests')?sc_apikey={{sitecore-master-apikey}}
```

I also have this returning the child items of that item:

```
GET https://{{sitecorehost}}/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('{{sitecorehome}}/banners-tests/Subcontent/Image and Texts')/Children?sc_apikey={{sitecore-master-apikey}}
```

However, because the children are not immediate children - they are two levels down at `/Subcontent/Image and Texts` - I cannot request them. Yes, I could search for them, but then *any* items would come back with the matching criteria and I only want to search items under that particular path.

I would like something which, I imagine, would look something like this:

```
GET https://{{sitecorehost}}/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items?sc_apikey={{sitecore-master-apikey}}&$filter=Name eq 'banner' and Path eq 'banners-tests'
```

Or perhaps this:

```
GET https://{{sitecorehost}}/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('{{sitecorehome}}/banners-tests')/Children?sc_apikey={{sitecore-master-apikey}}&$filter=Name eq 'banner'
```

But these do not work.

Answer (score 1):

@Matt We can do filtering based on the item path. For example, considering item path as :

- 'sitecore/content/home/tenant1/Subcontent/Image and Texts/neededitem' - the one needed
- 'sitecore/content/home/tenant1/Subcontent/Image and
  Texts/item1/neededitem/notneededitem' - the one we need to exclude

since '/' is not a valid character in the Sitecore item name and indicates the children of the needed item.
Hence, it can be used as a filter in javascript.
So we can split by 'Image and Texts' and then find the items.
For example, consider an array of results and let us say object with a collection of items is items and item path of each item is denoted by Path(let's say, this can be some other property as well) property

```js
let items = [{
  Path: 'sitecore/content/home/tenant1/Subcontent/Image and Texts/neededitem',
  anotherProperty: 'text-val1'
}, {
  Path: 'sitecore/content/home/tenant1/Subcontent/Image and Texts/item1/neededitem/notneededitem',
  anotherProperty: 'text-val2'
}];
const results = items.filter(item => {
  const splittedPath = item.Path.split('Image and Texts');
  if (splittedPath[1].split("/").length <= 2) {
    return item;
  }
});
console.log(results);
```

In case your SSC controller (C#) is custom one and having access to Sitecore Context object or Sitecore APIs then the GetChildren() method of Item class will bring children of first level only.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I think you've answered my question in your last paragraph (that what I want is not possible.) I am not using C# here, I am using Postman to submit requests directly via the rest api. Sorry if I missed that; I have edited the question. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that what you're telling me is that the client (in your case, javascript-based) is performing the multiple calls required to retrieve the child items and the client itself performs the filtering of those sub items. I was hoping for the api to provide that sub content itself.

Comment: Earlier the API call used to return only one level child and now with the latest Sitecore versions, it returns all the children. I thought of using parent as parameter in endpoint but since do not have a local instance so ended up with filtering logic.

Comment: How would I structure the GET restful call to return all child nodes of the path?

Comment: @MattW I believe we can make use Axios/fetch in javascript and then use the GET endpoint, wherein the item path can be configuration oriented. Did this answer the question?